# How to get nearest Bluetooth Device List in Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, swift3, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

I am trying to get the nearest Bluetooth using [CoreBluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothOverview/CoreBluetoothOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH2-SW1) framework, I import framework and implement `CBCentralManagerDelegate`, `CBPeripheralDelegate`.

Here is my code:

```
import CoreBluetooth

        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        guard central.state  == .poweredOn else {
            return
        }
        scanDevice()
    }

    func scanDevice() {

        centralManager?.scanForPeripherals(
            withServices: [transferServiceUUID], options: [
                CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : NSNumber(value: true as Bool)
            ]
        )
    }
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {

        print("Discovered \(peripheral.name) at \(RSSI)")
        if discoveredPeripheral != peripheral {
            discoveredPeripheral = peripheral
            print("Connecting to peripheral \(peripheral)")
            centralManager?.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
        }
    }
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didFailToConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
        print("Failed to connect to \(peripheral). (\(error!.localizedDescription))")

    }
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        print("Peripheral Connected")

        // Stop scanning
        centralManager?.stopScan()
        print("Scanning stopped")

        // Clear the data that we may already have
        data.length = 0

        // Make sure we get the discovery callbacks
        peripheral.delegate = self

        // Search only for services that match our UUID
        peripheral.discoverServices([transferServiceUUID])
    }
```

Why didn't I get nearest device list?

Comment: Are you sure that your peripheral is advertising a service with the `transferServiceUUID`?

Comment: [Github Example Libraries](https://github.com/rhummelmose/BluetoothKit) Try using these libraries and add them to your application.

Comment: Actually I am not getting neartest device. I am using Apple guideline to it. Can you help me out?

Comment: Try first with `centralManager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices:nil, options:theSame)`.

Comment: @Larme I get some of list for device. I am not sure they are correct or not. Even I didn't able to get name of device also.

Comment: You can get a name of a peripheral from delegate method

    func didReadPeripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, rssi: NSNumber) {let name = peripheral.name }